# Как редактировать Polygon Collider 2D не входя в Edit Collider режим после каждого клика?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Редактирую *Polygon Collider 2D* и после расположения, какой либо, вершины нужно снова входить в режим *Edit Collider*. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог редактировать коллайдер не входя в этот режим после каждого клика?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно проблема в том, что вы находитесь в режиме редактирования префаба и у вас включена галочка "Auto save". Благодаря этому параметру, юнити сохраняет ваш префаб при малейшем изменении любых его настроек - в том числе при изменении вершин коллайдера.

Попробуйте выключить данную галочку (сверху справа окна, возле кнопки Save). Главное, потом не забудьте сохранить ваши изменения.